# How to force gorm to give database object not the cached instance?

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have a requirement that whenever the `Data` domain class is updated the old values should be stored into a database table in JSON format so that it can be audited anytime after that.

Here I have three classes:

- `Data` - super class
- `User` - subclass (there are other subclasses too)
- `History` - table which needs to hold the old data

```
class Data implements Serializable {
    Date dateCreated
    Date lastUpdated
    User createdBy
    User updatedBy
    Status status
    static mapping = { tablePerHierarchy false }

    def beforeUpdate() {
        def jsonData  = (Data.get(this) as JSON).toString()
        new History(data:jsonData, domain: this.class.toString(), refid: this.id).save()
    }
}

class User extends Data {
    String name
    static constraints = {}
}


class History {

    String data
    Date dateCreated
    String domain
    Date lastUpdated
    long refid

    static constraints = {}
}
```

The method `beforeUpdate()` inside `Data` domain class is fetching the current values as JSON not the old values (which are there in database):

```
def jsonData  = (Data.get(this) as JSON).toString()
```

I am looking for some kind of method which will get the whole object with current values in the database.

Comment: have your tried .refresh() method?

Answer (score 1):

You can use method `refresh()` on the loaded object. Like `this.refresh()`.

Or you can use a new hibernate session for loading:

```
def jsonData 
withNewSession {
    jsonData = (Data.get(this) as JSON).toString()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do need to do this yourself, you can manually access the dirty/persistent properties easily enough.  E.g.,

```
def beforeUpdate() {
    println("Dirty properties: ${listDirtyPropertyNames()}")
    Map map = [:]
    listDirtyPropertyNames().each { name ->
      println("Dirty property: ${name} ----  old value: ${getPersistentValue(name)}  -----  new Value: " + this."${name}")
      map.put(name, getPersistentValue(name))
    }
    def jsonData = (map as JSON).toString()
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't directly answer your question, but you might consider plugins that provide this functionality for you rather than reinventing the wheel (albeit, not in JSON, but in ways that allow you to Audit old data, who and when the data was changed).  See http://plugins.grails.org/plugin/robertoschwald/audit-logging for example